# 'UIViewController' is not a subtype of 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am using a tab bar controller and I'm trying to access the defaults from my other tab bar view controller. I tried this in a different function, also shown below, and it works perfectly, but for some reason it isn't working here. It puts up the error whenever this is called: `FirstViewController().defaults`. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

            let cell = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            TableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            var photo: Photo
            let description = FirstViewController().description

            if(searchController.isActive){
                photo = self.filteredPhotos[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                photo = self.photosArray[indexPath.row]
            }
            cell.textLabel!.text = photo.name
            if(FirstViewController().defaults.data(forKey: photo.name + "image") as UIImage != nil){
                cell.imageView?.image = FirstViewController().defaults.data(forKey: photo.name + "image") as UIImage
            }
            print(photo.name)
            print("TableView2Finished")
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: You are trying to access defaults on the class FirstViewController, and not on an instance of FirstViewController. Is that intentional? Do you actually realize what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the instance of the FirstViewController, not the actual class definition.

Instead of this:

```
if(FirstViewController().defaults.data(forKey: photo.name + "image") as UIImage != nil) {
    cell.imageView?.image = FirstViewController().defaults.data(forKey: photo.name + "image") as UIImage
}
```

Try this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let firstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
if(firstViewController.defaults.data(forKey: photo.name + "image") as UIImage != nil) {
    cell.imageView?.image = firstViewController.defaults.data(forKey: photo.name + "image") as UIImage
}
```

Make sure you set a `Storyboard Identifier` for your FirstViewController so that you can reference it by the identifier in code.

**EDIT #1:**

Alternatively, you can save the string name to `UserDefaults` and access it that way.

In your first view controller:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(photo.name, forKey: "FirstImage")
```

In your table view controller:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let myImage = defaults.object(forKey: "FirstImage") as? String {
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: myImage!)
}
```