# 'UIViewController' is not a subtype of 'View Controller' Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have my class `LoginInfo` `Class` to access the information in multiple `View Controllers`. However, xCode spits an error of `UIViewController is not a subtype of Start_BirthdayVC'`. I can't seem to figure out why xCode is spitting that error.

```
class LoginInfo {


    func userInfo() {
        var firstName: String = ""
        var lastName: String = ""
        var dateOfBirth: String = ""
        var email: String = ""

        firstName = NameVC().firstNameText!.text!
        lastName = NameVC().lastNameText!.text!
        dateOfBirth = String(Start_BirthdayVC().datePicker.date) //Error here
        email = Start_EmailVC().emailTextField!.text!



    }


}
```

Comment: Your code won't do what you want even if it did compile because you are allocating new instances of your view controllers; you need to have the view controllers update your model, not have your model try and get data from the view controllers, which requires your model to have references to the actual,VC instances.

Comment: The line you have flagged should not give that error. I suspect your problem is in some other line, but as per my first comment, this code isn't the code you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems your UIViewController initialization is incorrect.
The second problem is that  you use have to use this:

`class Start_BirthdayVC: UIViewController { ... }`
You have to post `Start_BirthdayVC`.

Possibly, your code will crash at runtime due to you use implicitly unwrapped optional (exclamation marks).

Usually, UI items like `firstNameText` are not defined at initializer. Check it and post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access to the instance of the Start_BirthdayVC, such is replied in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42214739/3046686) thread.

So try to change

```
dateOfBirth = String(Start_BirthdayVC().datePicker.date) //Error here
```

to

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let startBirthdayVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Start_BirthdayViewController") as! Start_BirthdayVC
//access startBirthdayVC properties
```